# Enviroment.NewLine returns blank space

Tags: .net, vb.net

I'm using Enviroment.NewLine property to separate lines of string of characters that I will send via email through an smtpclient. I will omit the part of declaring the mail message.

For example:

```
Dim sb as StringBuilder
sb.Append("This is my first line")
sb.Append(Enviroment.NewLine)
sb.Append("This is my second line")
```

When I do a:

```
myMailMessage.Body = sb.ToString
```

No lines are separated. I debugged and noticed that Enviroment.NewLine is returning " "

I don't understand why it is happening, it is supposed to return a break line.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Environment.NewLine is not aware it is going to a message body

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `Enviroment.NewLine` put `<br/>`. And check the email in an email client.

Comment: If you use `<br/>` then ensure that `myMailMessage.IsBodyHtml` is set to `true`.

Comment: Thanks. I solved the problem. You all are right.

That code I'm using is right, but I have to set IsBodyHtml=false.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

1. `Enviroment.NewLine` might show as empty string in the debugger (because there are no printable symbols).
2. `Enviroment.NewLine` is platform specific to the platform you are running your code on, not to the platform of email reader. I would just use `"\r\n"` as it covers both, *nix and Windows. If your email is not plain-text, you can use `<br/>`.

Comment: Thanks. I solved the problem. You all are right.

That code I'm using is right, but I have to set IsBodyHtml=false.

Thanks again.